# Reading in a separate file for use in an ado file (relative path)

Tags: stata

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835165/paths-to-do-file-in-stata) suggests that it might not be possible, but I thought I would ask anyways. I am writing a Stata package in which the main `.ado` file needs to read in another (javascript) file to write out to the final result.

Essentially, I am trying to do the following in Stata

**Edit : Added code example**

```
program define injectFile
  /*
    Read a file (`1') and write it line by line
    to another file (`2'). Both files should be 
    passed as file object handles.
  */
  file read `1' line
  while r(eof) == 0 {
    if ("`3'" == "1") {
      file write `2' `"`macval(line)'"' "\n" 
    }
    else {
      file write `2' `"`macval(line)'"' _n //"
    }
    file read `1' line
  }
end

program generateChart

  tempname thtml_file
  tempname tcsv_file
  tempname tjs_fil

  // !!!!!!!! Relevant to the question !!!!!!!
  // need to access this file which should be located in the same
  // directory as this .ado file
  local script script.js


  // Open all the component files for the chart
  file open `thtml_file' using "out.html", write `replace'
  file open `tjs_file' using "`script'", read


  // The start of the new html file
  local html_top ///
  <html>  ///
    <head>  ///
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/htmlcharset=utf-8' / > ///
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>  ///
      <script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js'></script>  ///
    </head> ///
    <body> ///
      <div id='chart'></div> ///
      <script> 


  // Write the beginning of the html file
  file write `thtml_file' "`html_top'" _n

  // Insert the javascript
  injectFile `tjs_file' `thtml_file'

  // Close the htmlfile
  file write `thtml_file' "';</script></body></html>" 

end
```

Comment: I prefer to see code quoted here, not to have to go off somewhere, read your code and try to understand it. We just need to see minimal code that is pertinent to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added a minimal snippet.

Comment: Thanks for adding detail. Sergio's suggestion of `findfile` looks good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *findfile* to look for your ADO.

For instance:

```
. findfile ivreg2.ado
c:\ado\plus/i/ivreg2.ado

. di r(fn)
c:\ado\plus/i/ivreg2.ado
```

It also allows to search in folders different from the working directory and the ADO path

Looking forward to seeing your package, although I agree with Nick Cox regarding the etiquette rules

Comment: This sounds like a good option, I didn't know about `findfile`, thanks for the pointer!