# Stata change directory to the directory where this do file is

Tags: stata

I learned

```
cd
```

can help me to change the directory.

However, I need to make sure my do file works in other computers.

So I want a line in the do file that changes the directory to the directory that this do file exists.

How can I do this? Things like

```
cd ..
```

didn't do it..

Comment: People using other computers have to be told where the do-file is, do they not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is already answered by Nick Cox in a previous question: [Paths to do-file in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835165/paths-to-do-file-in-stata)

Pass do file with full directory path as argument.